# Embedding a number field in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a finitely generated field extension and let $(x_1,\cdots,x_m)$ be a transcendance basis of $K/\mathbb{Q}$. Using primitive element theorem, there exists $y\in K$ algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\cdots,x_m)$ such that: $$K=\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\cdots,x_m)[y].$$ 
Let $G$ be the minimal polynomial of $y$ in $K/\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\cdots,x_m)$, clearing the denominators, one may assume that $G\in\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\cdots,x_m][Y]$. Hence, there exists $H\in\mathbb{Z}[X_1,\cdots,X_m,Y]$ such that: $$G(Y)=H(x_1,\cdots,x_m,Y).$$
After some work, one can show that there exists a rational prime number $p$, $(\xi_1,\cdots,\xi_m)$ algebraically independent elements of $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Q}$ and $z\in{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ such that: $$H(\xi_1,\cdots,\xi_m,z)=0.$$

> **Question.** Why does there exist a $\mathbb{Q}$-isomorphism of $K$ such that $\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}x_i&\mapsto&\xi_i\\y&\mapsto&z\end{array}\right.$?

I know that if $L/K$ is a field extension, $f\in L[X]$ is an irreducible polynomial over $K$ and $x,y$ are two roots of $f$, then there exists a $K$-isomorphism of $L$ sending $x$ on $y$.

Any hint is greatly appreciated!

Reference: [J.W.S. Cassels, *An embedding theorem for field*, **1976**.](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FBAZ%2FBAZ14_02%2FS000497270002503Xa.pdf&code=f9c446f8678ac486a22b52fd9ff5084a)

Comment: This looks like a special case of the evaluation homomorphism, and it looks like we can use algebraic independence to imply that it is injective.

Comment: Maybe it’s too late at night, but I don’t see what the problem is. If you believe your sentence “After some work,...”, isn’t $\Bbb Q(x_1,\cdots,x_m)$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Q(\xi_1,\cdots,\xi_m)$? And once you have that, isn’t the defining polynomial for $y$ the “same” as the defining polynomial for $z$? Aren’t these two polynomials equally irreducible over those purely transcendental extensions of $\Bbb Q$? If I’m missing something, please point it out.

Comment: @Lubin Yes, that is what I am seeing as well.  I think Falcon wants to do it formally.

Comment: If I understood your points correctly, since $(x_1,\cdots,x_m)$ and $(\xi_1,\cdots,\xi_m)$ are algebraically independents over $\mathbb{Q}$, the evaluations maps of $\mathbb{Q}[X_1,\cdots,X_m]$ are bijective onto their ranges and induces (by universal property of the fraction field) isomorphisms between $\mathbb{Q}(X_1,\cdots,X_m)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\cdots,x_m)$, $\mathbb{Q}(\xi_1,\cdots,\xi_m)$. Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\cdots,x_m)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\xi_1,\cdots,\xi_m)$ are isomorphic and $y$ and $z$ have the same minimal polynomial up to this isomorphism. Whence the result. Am I right?